# How to take out ones of commit from a branch

Tags: git, jira

There's a branch containing hundreds of commits and each commit associated with a Jira ticket.

There's a commit(jira tickets have been in the history in remote branch)

how can I remove the specific commit (jira ticket) from the branch?

When merging the branch with another destination branch, I would like to exclude the unused commit(jira)

What's the simple way to do?

Comment: If you need to actually remove a commit buried deep somewhere in your branch, you would have to use something like filter-branch or interactive rebase.  But if you just need to undo that commit's functionality, you could use `git revert`.

Comment: Merge the branch and then revert that commit. The commit is still part of the history, but its changes are gone away from the current branch.